# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 null(Spring Resttemplate)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I try to get list of entity with using rest template, but I get 415 error in line:

```
ResponseEntity<List<ResponseOrderDto>> responseEntity = rest.exchange
```

My implementation:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        rest.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
            ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request,body);
            response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            response.getHeaders().add("Bearer", contentToken);
            return response;
        });
        ResponseEntity<List<ResponseOrderDto>> responseEntity = rest.exchange(
                ORDER_SERVICE_URL + "/by-user",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ResponseOrderDto>>() {
                });
```

How fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

415 means unsupported content type, so the Content-type header is not correctly set.

Based on your code, I think that the request needs JSON Content-Type header, but you set the content-type header on the response instead of the request.

Change your interceptor to be something like this:

```
      rest.getInterceptors().add((request, body, execution) -> {
        request.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        request.getHeaders().add("Bearer", contentToken);
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        return response;
      });
```

To set the headers at the right time to the request